# How do I login facebook android sdk 3.15.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying facebook sdk 3.15.0. I want to do just Login facebook. I read documentation Fulfill. When I do run my project then I is crashed. But I can not understand where my Error. Please help me

```
   07-10 03:11:33.582: E/Trace(5933): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-10 03:11:34.981: D/AndroidRuntime(5933): Shutting down VM
07-10 03:11:34.981: W/dalvikvm(5933): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fbapps/com.example.fbapps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at com.example.fbapps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     ... 11 more
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     ... 21 more
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.fbapps-1.apk
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
07-10 03:11:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5933):     ... 24 more
```

I replace com.facebook.scrumptious but this problem is same
XML layout:

```
<fragment android:name="com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [Facebook Login Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate) said :

`The authenticated UI is represented by a fragment you'll create named SelectionFragment.`

So you must define the `SelectionFragment` by yourself. Then in your activity_main.xml setup:

```
<fragment android:name="com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You **must replace** `com.facebook.scrumptious` with **your package name**

Comment: thanks for answer,  already i have done this but same problem.

Comment: show same problem in logcat bro please can you give me your Email id then I can to give full code.

Comment: The same problem mean you didn't replace `com.facebook.scrumptious` with your package name, so the compiler couldn't find the `SelectionFragment` class in the `com.facebook.scrumptious` package.